# How do I make nginx act as both a proxy and web server?

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, varnish

I have nginx set up as an ssl reverse proxy to varnish with apache backend and it works perfectly but now I need nginx to act as a web server for one directory.

```
server {
    listen 10.0.0.20:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 10.0.0.20:443 ssl spdy backlog=16384;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /home/ubuntu/mydomain-ssl/mydomain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /home/ubuntu/mydomain-ssl/mydomain.key;
        ssl_dhparam /home/ubuntu/mydomain-ssl/dh2048.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Public-Key-Pins 'pin-sha256="gFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10Q"; pin-sha256="gFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10QgFcziPQKxI10Q";  max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains';
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header  X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        }
}
```

If someone could show a simple example of how I could serve the directory /directory/ as part of this config it would be super helpful, I have tried configuring by adding additional location blocks but it didn't work, I just got 404 errors when accessing the directory.

Comment: Basically I am trying to add the sendy configuration here http://ckailash.com/tag/install-sendy-on-subdirectory-nginx/ but not as a complete server, just as a non-proxied nginx served directory included in the config in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a default location that redirects traffic to https and a more specific location that just serves files:

```
server {
    listen 10.0.0.20:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # absolute path to your directory
    root /var/www/www.example.com/directory;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; 
    }

    location /directory/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nginx is acting as an SSL terminator so that part needs to stay the same, I tried adding a /directory/ block and all I got was 404 errors for PHP, I could access .txt files fine though.  When I got the 404 errors I set up a separate config on port 80 from a different IP and it worked fine, so I know the sendy config is good and the permissions seem correct.